# Error in percentage of areas calculation in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

I have been trying to calculate percentage of areas of each class in GEE but I'm getting error and it says that left value is invalid type. And left value is usually list of all the class areas. This is my code:

```
var geom = table.geometry();
Map.centerObject(geom, 13);
Map.addLayer(geom, {color: 'red'}, 'Dubai');

//How I got the image. You can uncomment this and run the code
// var img= ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2").filterDate('2000-06-01', '2000-06-30')
//           .filterBounds(geom);
// print(img)

var l5= ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2/LT05_160043_20000628').unmask();

Map.addLayer(l5.clip(geom), imageVisParam, 'L5 1990');

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////UNSUPERVISED CLASSIFICATION////////////////////////////////////


// Make the training dataset.
var training = l5.sample({
  region: geom,
  scale: 30,
  numPixels: 5000
});

// Instantiate the k mean clusterer and train it.
var clustererK = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(3).train(training);
var kmeansresult = l5.cluster(clustererK);

// Display the clusters with random colors.
Map.addLayer(kmeansresult.randomVisualizer().clip(geom), {}, 'K mean clusters', false);
//print(clustererK,'K means');

///////////////////////////////
// Divide the area image by 1e6 so area results are in Sq Km
var unareaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(kmeansresult);
print(unareaImage,'Unareaimage');


// Using a Grouped Reducer
var unareas = unareaImage.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'classification',
    }),
    geometry: geom,
    scale: 100,
    tileScale: 4,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    }); 
    
var classAreasun = ee.List(unareas.get('groups'))
print(classAreasun, 'Unareas')


var unareaChart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image: unareaImage,
  classBand: 'cluster', 
  region: geom,
  scale: 100,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  classLabels: ['NonBuiltup', 'Water', 'Builtup'],
}).setOptions({
  hAxis: {title: 'Classes'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Area Km^2'},
  title: 'Area by class',
  series: {
    0: { color: 'fde0be' },
    1: { color: '4a34d6' },
    2: { color: 'ff5d33' }
  }
});
print(unareaChart); 

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////SUPERVISED CLASSIFICATION ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Bands
//calculating indices for 1990
var blue = l5.select('SR_B1');
var green= l5.select('SR_B2');
var red = l5.select('SR_B3');
var nir_1 = l5.select('SR_B4');
var nir_2 = l5.select('SR_B5');
var mir= l5.select('SR_B7');


//NDVI and NDBI for 1990
var ndvi = nir_1.subtract(red).divide(nir_1.add(red)).rename('NDVI_1');
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(geom), ndv, 'NDVI 1990', false);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////CLASSIFICATION////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////Classification of 2005//////////////////////////////////////////

var merge= blue.addBands(green).addBands(red).addBands(nir_1).addBands(nir_2).addBands(mir).addBands(ndvi);
var bands = merge.bandNames();
var samples = Water.merge(Builtup).merge(NonBuiltup)
// extract band values from the input image 1990
var sampleval = merge.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: samples,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30}).randomColumn();

Water = Water.set('landcover', 0,'type', 'Water')
// Train the classifier
var training = sampleval.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.7));
var validation = sampleval.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', 0.7));

// define the random forest classier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100).train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: 'landcover', 
  inputProperties: bands
});
var classified = ee.Image(merge.classify(classifier).clip(geom));
// Display the inputs and the results.
Map.addLayer(classified.clip(geom), {min: 0, max: 2, palette: ['4a34d6', 'ff5d33', 'fde0be']}, 'Classification of Year 1990');

//Validate the results of 1990
print(classifier.explain());

var validated = validation.classify(classifier);
//print(validated);

var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Validation consumers accuracy: ', testAccuracy.consumersAccuracy());
print('Validation producers accuracy: ', testAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
print('Validation kappa value: ', testAccuracy.kappa());



// Create a 2 band image with the area image and the classified image
// Divide the area image by 1e6 so area results are in Sq Km
var areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(classified);
print(areaImage);


// Calculate Area by Class
// Using a Grouped Reducer
var areas = areaImage.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'classification',
    }),
    geometry: geom,
    scale: 100,
    tileScale: 4,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    }); 
    
var classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups'))
print(classAreas)


var areaChart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image: areaImage,
  classBand: 'classification', 
  region: geom,
  scale: 100,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  classLabels: ['Water', 'Builtup', 'NonBuiltup'],
}).setOptions({
  hAxis: {title: 'Classes'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Area Km^2'},
  title: 'Area by class',
  series: {
    0: { color: '4a34d6' },
    1: { color: 'ff5d33' },
    2: { color: 'fde0be' }
  }
});
print(areaChart); 
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified.clip(geom),
  description: 'classified',
  maxPixels: 518232528,
  scale: 30,
  region: geom
});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ac7169c590b007e6da99da373f9f336b

I have completely removed the percentage code.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have completely removed the percentage calculation in your code so, I don't know where your problem was. However, it is very easy to calculate the percentages of areas with remaining lines.

Percentages are a sort of normalization where all values sum 100 instead of 1. So, where you are defining **areaImage** variable (square km) as follows:

```
var areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(classified);
```

you need to define **areaImage** variable (percentage) instead with following lines:

```
var totalArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geom,
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

totalArea = totalArea.get("area");

var areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(ee.Number(totalArea))
                                    .multiply(100).addBands(classified);
```

I put above lines in your code and it can be run at following [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/158affaa420449cfa3e28962a964b6e9). I commented several lines for only producing your cart in square km and my normalized cart as percentages.

Produced result can be observed in following picture:

[image]

Area represented by **NonBuiltup** class is 74.352 %. Sum of all areas is about 100 %.